# What exactly should you return from a redux slice reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Today I had a bug where my components which were using `useSelector` wouldn't re-render when my redux state changed. After a quick read through the `createSlice` documentation I noticed that they were returning the `state.something = action.payload`, which I wasn't doing.

So in this code:

```
const personSlice = createSlice({
  name: "person",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setToken: (state, action) => {
      state.token = action.payload;
    },
    setUser: (state, action) => {
      state = { ...state, ...action.payload };
    },
  },
});
```

when I set the token, my app would update and it was working fine. But after dispatching the `setUser` action, my components which depended on the `person` state were not getting re-rendered. But then why did it work when I was setting the token without returning?

I changed my code to this:

```
const personSlice = createSlice({
  name: "person",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setToken: (state, action) => {
      state.token = action.payload;
    },
    setUser: (state, action) => {
      return state = { ...state, ...action.payload };
    },
  },
});
```

and everything works just fine, even without the `return` in `setToken`.

So I guess my ultimate question is, what exactly happens in a slice, why and what do I need to return from actions?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`createSlice` uses Immer inside. Immer works by either:

- tracking *mutations* to an existing `state` object, like `state.x = 123`
- letting you *return* a new value, like `return {...state, x: 123}

Assigning `state = anything` is not a mutation, and it doesn't return anything. It just reassigns the *local variable named `state`* to point to something else.

If you want to "merge in" some data, then yes, you need to either `return {...state, ...someData}`, or use `Object.assign(state, someData)` to "mutate" the existing `state` object.

Please see [the Redux Toolkit "Writing Reducers with Immer" usage guide](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers), which covers this topic.

Comment: So if I do `state.x = 123` it doesn't actually change the state, but Immer just 'picks up' on the change and mutates the state for me?

Comment: Yes. Immer tracks your _attempted_ change to the `draftState` using a Proxy, mutates the draft now to let you keep making changes, but then replays all of your changes immutably once you are done to create the final immutably-updated result.

Comment: Thanks that explained everything to me.